# why am i getting the error : window is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var myurl = window.location.href;
console.log(myurl);
```

I have run the above js file in my computer and iam getting an

> error : window is not defined.

i did not find the answer anywhere.

What am i doing wrong? Is there anything i need to add to the code ? 
Can someone tell me how window.location works And how to get rid of the error.

Comment: You're running code in Node.js. There is no `window`.

Comment: If you're running in node, what "URL" do you expect there to be…?

Comment: @deceze Just wondering, why this question got closed as offtopic? May I know what is offtopic here ? Should be closed as some other reason ?

Comment: @Suresh It's clear what the error is, it's unclear what the OP is trying to accomplish with this. We can't offer any solution other than "it doesn't work, simply don't do this", which I think is self-evident enough. *("must include the desired behavior")*

Comment: @deceze fair enough. Looks like OP trying to get the request url or he is running wrong js file on node. Anyway *IMHO* that  comes under `Too Broad`.  Let it be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no global `window` object in NodeJS

Comment: oh okay. Thanks . I didnt know that .